# Convert decimal to hex in Lua 4?

Tags: lua, hex, type-conversion

I found this formula to convert decimal numbers to hexadecimal color values in Lua:

http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2004-09/msg00054.html

However, I have a few questions about the formula:

1. My input needs to be normalized between 0 and 1 instead of 0 and 255. Is this a potential problem?
2. I am stuck with Lua 4.01 instead of whatever the latest version is. I can't upgrade. Is this a problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure its Lua 4.1 and not 5.1? Lua 5.1 is still commonly used (since its the Lua version supported by LuaJIT) but Lua 4.1 is very very old and you will have a hard time finding good documentation for it! https://www.lua.org/versions.html

Comment: According to [Lua site](https://www.lua.org/versions.html) there is no such version 4.1

Comment: Can you give examples of the inputs and outputs that you want? I usually see hexadecimal being used for integers so using them for things between 0 and 1 is a bit unusual.

Comment: Input 0.5, Output 80

Comment: *"My input needs to be normalized between 0 to 1 instead of 0 to 255."*  What does that mean? The routine you linked to doesn't normalize the input. Also, the routine you linked to could be replaced with `string.format('%x')`.

Comment: @Mud - There is no `string` table in Lua 4.0

Comment: @posfan12 - `output = format("%02x", input*256)`

Comment: Format works, guys, thank you! BTW, in Lua 4.01 you don't need to specify the string table. You just call the function like any other.

Comment: https://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/manual.html#6.2

see https://www.lua.org/source/4.0/lstrlib.c.html for the c implementation

Comment: Egor had the right answer.

Answer (score 18):

In Lua 5.x you can use the string.format function with the `%x` format specifier to convert integers to their hexadecimal representation. In your case it would look like this:

```
local input = 0.5
local output = string.format("%x", input * 255) -- "7F"
```

I don't know Lua 4.0.1 well so I can't tell you if this function is available (perhaps under a different name). That said, if its not, then you might be able to workaround by turning this into a C function that uses `sscanf`.

Answer (score 0):

The example function demonstrated at
http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2004-09/msg00054.html
does not converts negative numbers.
Here is an example of conversion for both, negative and positive numbers:

```
function decimalToHex(num)
    if num == 0 then
        return '0'
    end
    local neg = false
    if num < 0 then
        neg = true
        num = num * -1
    end
    local hexstr = "0123456789ABCDEF"
    local result = ""
    while num > 0 do
        local n = math.mod(num, 16)
        result = string.sub(hexstr, n + 1, n + 1) .. result
        num = math.floor(num / 16)
    end
    if neg then
        result = '-' .. result
    end
    return result
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But `string` and `math` are Lua 5 objects.

Answer (score 0):

Example with converting [negative dec to positive hex](https://technosoftmotion.com/en/knowledge-base/the-negative-numbers-representation-in-hex/#:%7E:text=The%20hexadecimal%20value%20of%20a,the%20respective%20negative%20decimal%20number.).

```
local input = -0.5
local output = string.format("%x", math.floor(input * 255)):sub(-2) -- 80
```

If you need to convert a non-two-digit hex number, change the `string.sub` argument. For Lua 4.01:

```
local input = -0.5
local output = strsub(format("%x", floor(input * 255)), -2) -- 80
```