# Keeping a hex addition result as hex lua

Tags: lua

I've got the following code in lua:

```
array = {}
for i=1, 30 do
    mem = tostring(0x29A300 + (i * 0x11CC))
    array[i] = "Ref Mem" .. i .. ": " .. mem
 end
```

But when I do the hexadecimal addition to store in mem, I get a decimal value out.
Is there a way to keep the hex formatting that I used to do the calculation?
Also is there a way for me to remove the 0x in the string?

I've tried using tonumber but that gives me an error.
There hasn't been anything else I've tried as I'm completely new to lua.

Comment: `array[i] = "Ref Mem" .. i .. ": " .. string.format("%x", mem)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff can you make that an answer so I can upvote it? Also... THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert decimal to hex in Lua 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796287/convert-decimal-to-hex-in-lua-4)